# Laravel 5.1, nested validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

Lets say I have a form like this:

(The O's represent checkbox input)

```
O - Pizza option
O - Free beer with pizza
O - I want extras on my pizza
---- O - cheese
---- O - funghi
---- O - ham
---- O - something else
```

User can select pizza and  free beer, but also some extras. Out of these extras he needs to chose at least one ingredient but only if extra option is selected.

My validation is as follows:

```
'extras.cheese' => 'required_without_all:funghi,ham,something_else',
'extras.funghi' => 'required_without_all:cheese,ham,something_else',
'extras.ham' => 'required_without_all:cheese,funghi,something_else',
'extras.something_else' => 'required_without_all:cheese,funghi,ham',
```

However I want these to apply only if `extraOption` is selected. In other words I want to nest these rules inside of `required_if:extraOption,1` rule.

EDIT:

I guess I need a custom validator that will look something like:

`'extras.cheese' => 'required_if_then_required_without_all:extraOption,funghi,ham,something_else'`

where the first option will go to the `required_if` part of the function, and rest of the options to `required_without_all` part.

I will edit my question as I move along.

EDIT 2:

Following the documentation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules) I added code below to `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    Validator::extend('required_if_then_required_without_all', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return true;
    });
```

Now I need to figure out what is what and how to implement the logic.

EDIT3:

This is what I thought should work but it doesn't. It always passes validation.

```
    Validator::extend('required_if_then_required_without_all', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        $required_if = $parameters[0];
        $required_without_all = array_except($parameters, [0]); // remove entry with key 0 from $parameters array
        $value = false;
        if($required_if != 1)
        {
            $value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($required_without_all as $r)
            {
                if ( $r == 1) { $value = true; }
            }

        }
        return $value;
    });
```

And I call it as:

```
    'cheese' => 'required_if_then_required_without_all:extraOption,funghi,ham,something_else',
```

UPDATE ON EDIT3:

Adding new validator as:

```
    Validator::extend('false', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        return false;
    });
```

And calling it as
         'cheese' => 'false',

does nothing.
I guess I'm doing something very wrong here and any help is appreciated.

2nd UPDATE TO EDIT3:

I think the problem is that `Form::checkbox` doesn't send any data if not selected so the validation is not triggered.

Calling `false` on `Form::text` works as excepted.

3rd UPDATE TO EDIT3:

Adding

`{!! Form::hidden('cheese',0) !!}`

before the checkbox made the field responsive to `false` Validator. But the `required_if_then_required_without_all` validator still doesn't get triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure:

```
    O - Pizza option
    O - Free beer with pizza
    O - I want extras on my pizza
    ---- O - cheese
    ---- O - funghi
    ---- O - ham
    ---- O - something else
```

Validator

```
    Validator::extend('required_with_one_of', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $data = $validator->getData();
        $count = [];
        foreach ($parameters as $p) {
            if ( array_get($data,$p) != null) {$count[] = array_get($data, $p);}
        }
        if(count($count) > 0 ) { return true; } else { return false;}
    });
```

which is applied to `extraOption` like

```
        'extraOption => 'required_with_one_of:options.cheese,options.funghi,options.ham,options.something_else',
```

The Checkboxes are:

```
    {!! Form::checkbox('extraOption', '1', false, ['id' => 'extraOption']) !!}

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        {!! Form::label('options[cheese]','Cheese:', ['class' => 'padding-right-10']) !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('options[cheese]', '1', false) !!}
    </div> ......
```

Comment: If anybody has the time please check if everything is as it should be. This is working but I want to know if something could be improved. Thanks.
ps. My code was not that simple but I think I edited everything according to this simplified example.