# laravel 5.1 form validation with foreach

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

In my app administrator can add `categories`, and `subcategories`. Each `category/subcategory` has an `id`, `name` and `slug`. Then the user can add an `article` and select if she wants to add a `category` and/or `subcategory` to that user.

This is done through input forms which looks like this

```
O - Add category 1 subcategories
O - Add category 2 subcategories
```

Where O are checkboxes. Clicking on `O - add category x subcategories`  will open list of subcategories as:

```
O - Add category 1 subcategories
 ----O - 1st subcat
 ----O - 2nd subcat
 ----O - 3rd subcat
O - Add category 2 subcategories
 ----O - 1st subcat
 ----O - 2nd subcat
 ----O - 3rd subcat
```

input id's are as `category1slug[subcategory1slug]`, `category1slug[subcategory2slug]`, and so on. They are rendered in a form with `foreach` loop as

```
foreach ( $categories as $category) { input field }
```

Now I want to validate these entries as follows. If `O - Add category 1 subcategories` field is selected I want at least one of the subcategories to be selected. The custom validation I have done is here:

[Laravel 5.1, nested validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568022/laravel-5-1-nested-validation)

However I don't know how to apply it to all of the categories. I want to get the validation as follows:

```
'category1slug' => 'required_with_one_of:category1slug.subcategory1slug,category1slug.subcategory2slug,category1slug.subcategory3slug',
'category2slug' => 'required_with_one_of:category2slug.subcategory3slug,category2slug.subcategory4slug,category2slug.subcategory5slug',
'category3slug' => 'required_with_one_of:category3slug.subcategory6slug,category3slug.subcategory7slug,category3slug.subcategory8slug',
```

but I don't want to have to add them manually every time since the data is already in the database. Also if I had to add them manually I would have to descend to `routes.php` every time an admin adds new category or subcategory or when he changes subcategory/category relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Request` file there is

```
public function rules()
{ 
  return [];
}
```

which returns array. Return array as:

```
public function rules()
{ 
  $therulesarray = [];

  foreach ( $categories as $category) { 
    //desired logic here
    $therulesarray['attribute'] = 'rulestoapply'; //this will add new element in $therulesarray that our function rules() returns;
  }
  return $therulesarray;
}
```

Some more info: http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/